# autocomplete and cache in Firefox

Tags: firefox, browser, browser-cache, local-storage

I am trying to understand if there is any difference between browser (in my case Firefox) cache and the place where 'autocomplete' data for an HTML form is stored in the browser. Unified storage for Firefox,
[Unified storage in Firefox](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Mozilla2:Unified_Storage),
mentions that 'saved passwords' are stored in a text file called 'signons.txt'. There is a next version of this file, 'signons2.txt', for the more recent versions of Firefox. [signons2.txt details](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Signons2.txt) gives details about this file.

> Now, is this storage the same as the browser cache, where http responses get cached ?

I came across [relation between cache and signons](http://www.experts-exchange.com/Software/Internet_Email/Web_Browsers/Q_24914720.html) that makes a mention as: **The signons.txt file is used to stored 'cached credentials' for users that choose to store usernames and passwords for sites they are visiting.**

> What exactly is the relation between cache and signons.txt (if at all there is) or any other such storage for that matter ?

There was another resource, [caches in Firefox](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Profile_folder_-_Firefox), that i came across that makes a mention of caches, offline caches and signups.txt in different sections. Just FYI in case it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at your profile directory:
`~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default`

There are the files
`formhistory.sqlite`,
used for form autocompletion and
`signons.sqlite`,
containing the saved passwords.

Both are independent of the cache in
`~/.cache/mozilla/firefox/*.default/Cache`